# AS3 - Simple text scramble encode/decoder?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, encryption, save

I am working on the saving/loading functionality of my AS3 game. I plan to let the player save their game to their hard drive from a browser-run game. I want to scramble the text I'm saving so a human can't really read it if they open the file as text.

What is a good method to scramble text before saving, and then unscramble after opening?

I know in Java it's possible to take a `char` and add or subtract from it to change the `char`, which was an extremely simple method. What can be done simply in ActionScript 3?

Keep in mind, I'm looking for simple and easy rather than secure. All of the cryptography sites I've checked for solution are more complicated than I can understand at this point, and are focused on making the most secure encryption rather than on easy integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do something similar to what you did in java.

Try:

```
var offset:int = 10;
for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

string[i] = string.charCodeAt(i) + offset;

}
```

Where `string` is the text you want to change, what this does is gets the numeric unicode value of the character at each index of the string and modifies it's value by offset.

To decode you run the same code but in reverse:

```
for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

string[i] = string.charCodeAt(i) - offset;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be getting a bit of the original topic with the fileReference.save() but I got here searching for this. Actually it couldn't be simpler:

```
var file:FileReference=new FileReference();
file.save(byteArrayData,"name you want to suggest to the user");
```

One thing to watch: You can only initiate inside a handler of the mouseEvent (CLICK). 
So the user has to request the write.
If you try to do it automtically it will work locally, but once you put it online, it won't!
Seems to be a relatively new badly documented security feature.
So if you had trouble making it work lately, it's probably that.

Here is a working online example, where you can save a PNG with a buttonpush:
http://www.snoep.at/misc/youtube/cloud_generator/

For this to work AT ALL your user need a fairly recent version of flashplayer (I think 10.1 and up), so if it doesn't work you might try an update.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reverse the text? That is a simple yet effective way.

Another would be to break the text in groups of 2 characters each, and reverse them, and then join the string again.

Answer (score 1):

[rot13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) would be nice and simple for this. I'm sure there are a few AS3 tutorials or [libraries](http://ascrypt3.riaforge.org/) out [there](http://www.laziomatica.com/web/archives/61). Another common option is [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), also with existing [libraries](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/util/Base64.as).

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna do this, why not use a established cryptography Cipher?

Get as3crypto from here http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/downloads/detail?name=Crypto.zip&can=2&q=

Then here's how to use RC4 (one of the many ciphers you can use):

```
import com.hurlant.util.Hex;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import com.hurlant.crypto.prng.ARC4;

var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("SUPER SECRET PASSWORD THAT YOUR USER WILL FIND OUT IF HE DECOMPILES YOUR SWF ANYWAY");
var pt:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("THIS IS THE ACTUAL FILE YOU'RE ENCRYPTING OR DECRYPTING");
var rc4:ARC4 = new ARC4(key);
rc4.encrypt(pt);
var out : String = Hex.fromArray(pt);
// save out to file

// load loadedFile from file
pt = Hex.toArray(loadedFile);
rc4.init(key);
rc4.decrypt(pt);
out = Hex.fromArray(pt);
// parse out's information
```

This might seem a little overkill but it actually is easier to use than to make your own encryption/decryption thing, and it has been tested and used a bunch of times.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. I'm going with the char shift method above with some modification, but if I was doing this for a professional project I'd probably go with this sort of solution.

Comment: Check this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868375/flash-as3-string-encode-decode (Juan Pablo solution)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you save the game, but if you use [Local Shared Objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html), your text is saved as binary data (while variable names remain human readable).

Comment: I'm planning to use two methods of saving - shared objects for auto-save, and files the user puts on their hard drive for manual saving.

Comment: Would you tell me more about the second method?

Comment: The plan is to have the player able to save a separate file using FileReference. They have to pick the location each time they save because of the limit flash (quite rightly) puts on browser apps, so I find the need to still save games to a shared object for automatic, regular saving. See [this code sample](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#includeExamplesSummary) for a way to load files from the user's hard drive.

Comment: I perfectly know how FileReference works. What I don't understand is how you write to file.

Comment: I haven't got to that part yet. I know there is a `save()` function for `FileReference`, so my thought is adding strings to a `ByteArray` until it's ready to be saved, assign it to the `FileReference`, then call `save()`? I'll be figuring this stuff out in the next few days.

Comment: Not sure about the result of adding strings to ByteArray and then saving to .txt, but recently you can save a file very easily this way:`var string = "my text";
var file = new FileReference();
file.save(string, "text.txt");` (some months ago it was possible only with AIR). Anyway, I would go rot13, as suggested by @kapep